# Transfer analog value via Bluetooth HC-05 (master) to second HC-05 (slave)

Tags: datalogging

II have setup a UNO and a HC-05 Bluetooth module as a 'Slave', and a NANO and an HC-05 Bluetooth module as 'Master', I believe the comm's work ok as I am receiving values and text, but the analog IN via a pot on the 'Master' (NANO) reads fine on the master Serial Screen, but does not read the same on the Slave (UNO)serial screen,the values received are changing from accurate to inaccurate on during data transfer.

I was hoping for a continuous accurate stream as the pot will be replaced with a 'load cell' and I need to capture weight readings and display them on a time base, I used bluetooth as the load cell and 'Slave' will be approx 5m apart. I would appreciate any help and I can send the sketch if you wish?

Regards, Gordon

Comment: do you have a question?

Comment: `and I can send the sketch if you wish?` -- It's not a wish - it's a requirement. There's no chance we can have even the slightest clue what is going on unless you show us your sketch (and by "show" I mean edit your question and include the text of the sketch in the question - not a photo, not a link, the text - and format it correctly with three back-ticks on the line before and three on the line after).